# Phpass - how to check login username and password against username and password hash in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, hash, phpass

I have successfully used Phpass to hash registered users passwords and store them in a database, now i am stuck on the login how to check the sumbitted username and password, checking the username exists in the database then checking the hashed password against the one given.

Any help much appreciated!!! Thankyou!

This is my code:

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('config.inc');

require("PasswordHash.php");
$hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Passwords should never be longer than 72 characters to prevent DoS attacks
if (strlen($password) > 72) { die("Password must be 72 characters or less"); }

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows = 1) {


$res = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '$username'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
$hash = $row['password']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash)) { //$hash is the hash retrieved from the      DB 
        $what = 'Authentication succeeded';
    } else {
        $what = 'Authentication failed';
    }

} else {

 echo "No Such User";
include 'login.php';
exit();
}

echo "$what\n";
echo "<br />";
echo "$hash";

?>
```

THIS IS MY WORKING CODE FOR BENEFIT OF OTHERS:

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('config.inc');

require("PasswordHash.php");
$hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Passwords should never be longer than 72 characters to prevent DoS attacks
if (strlen($password) > 72) { die("Password must be 72 characters or less"); }

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows = 1) {


$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
$hash = $row['password']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash)) { //$hash is the hash retrieved from the      DB 
        $what = 'Authentication succeeded';
    } else {
        $what = 'Authentication failed';
    }

} else {

 echo "No Such User";
include 'login.php';
exit();
}

echo "$what\n";
echo "<br />";
echo "$hash";

?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.  Not to mention that the mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should instead use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: please could you explain further which bits i can improve and how this would look? I am new to php and trying to learn, I understand i can ad the escape string and html special characters verfication in but at the moment i just want to get the login procedure working, do you know how i could do this? thankyou for any help you can offer

Comment: Please post the code of your CheckPassword function.

Comment: thanks, have added it in to the question

Comment: I try your code but there is an issue here try to put the user id and leave the password empty u will be able to login without passwords!! what the hell I have the same problem and I am try to solve it all the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) works: When you save the user's password (when they create it) you hash it before saving, like so:

```
$hash_iterations = 30;
$portable_hashes = FALSE;
$hasher = new PasswordHash($hash_iterations, $portable_hashes);
$hash_value = $hasher->HashPassword($actual_password);
```

Then save `$hash_value` in the database as the user's password. When you go to validate the user, look up the user by username. If found, compare the actual password from the database (stored hash) with a hash of what the user entered:

```
// $stored_hash is the value you saved in the database for this user's password
// $user_input is the POST data from the user with the actual password
$valid_password = $hasher->CheckPassword($user_input, $stored_hash);
```

Make sure to initialize the `PasswordHash` class the same way each time, with the same values for `$hash_iterations` and `$portable_hashes`, or the comparison won't work correctly.

Comment: thanks this has helped a lot!! i have adjusted my code accordingly but it is still saying authentication failed? i will ammend my original code, please could you take a look and see where i am going wrong, thank you!!

Comment: For one thing, you're using `$numrows = 1` which will always be TRUE (the result of an assignment to "1"), you want `$numrows == 1` or else it may try to fetch users that don't exist. You must make sure you stored the password originally the same exact way. Try from scratch by adding a new user, and make sure to use `PasswordHash(8, false)` (the same way you do the comparison) before hashing and saving the PW. If that fails for some reason, try with `$portable_hashes = TRUE`.

Comment: okay thankyou, i have checked the PasswordHash(8, false) is the same on both, when i echo out my $query it returns Resource id #11, any ideas on this? could it be that my query is not right?

Comment: Thankyou so much! just did a fresh user and authentication succeeded! checked by entering wrong username/password and it didnt let it pass through! you where a great help!

Comment: As a side note: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). 
You need to use the appropriate method of your database library
to escape your data prior to making the query...

Comment: ...Avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider learning about
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for starting.

Comment: thankyou, i will now look in to that, will using PDO or MySQLi have built in security features against SQL injection and such likes? and is it possible to simply update my existing code to new practices without having to rewrite everything?

Comment: No, you would have to update your code. At the very least, for now, make sure to run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on any variables and user input you use in your query.

Comment: Thank you for being attentive to your question and not disappearing, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mog I am facing a problem of checkpassword returning neither true nor false. The question and code is at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875775/checkpassword-issue-with-phpass hoping you can help me